# Azure DevOps Default Dashboard?

Tags: azure-devops, dashboard

I an administrator of a large corporate Azure DevOps (formerly VSTS) instance where we manage our application lifecycle management process.  We have hundreds of 'teams' within our main collection project; and each team has 1-5 dashboards for reporting their velocity, status, activity, etc.  We're attempting to (somewhat) standardize the dashboards and widgets on them; and any new teams dashboards within our 'mega' project when it's created.  Has anyone had any success in doing this, or atleast setting a standard default dashboard(s) when a new team is created?  THanks!

Comment: Did you look at the REST APIs available for dashboards?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "Template Dashboard" with all your default widgets and in another teams create a copy of the dashboard with the "[VSTS Copy Dashboard](https://vstscopydashboard.ecanarys.com/)" tool.

The VSTS Copy Dashboard tool helps overcome cumbersome process of replicating dashboards within multiple teams of the same VSTS project. It requires you to sign-in to your VSTS account, select the team project, choose the team with preset dashboard and then choose either single or multiple teams to which the dashboards have to be copied.

[image]

Comment: Shayki, thanks for your response and recommendation of using the 'VSTS Copy Dashboard' tool.  It does look like it would help us quite a bit as we attempt to replicate/standardize dashboards across our teams.  However, when I use the tool, and authenticate with my Microsoft account, it immediately gives me the following error message back from the vstscopydashborad.canarys.com site.  I tried in Chrome and IE with the same results.  Any ideas?

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error 
  Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Comment: I get also the same error. please send an email to vststoolssupport@ecanarys.com with the subject line "TFS Copy Dashboard Bug".

Comment: Shayki, I reached out to Canarys help, and got a response right away... looks like they're having trouble with their dashboard copy tool... Hi Dan,

Sorry for the inconvenience caused, we are facing some technical problem with the VSTS Copy Dashboard Tool.
We are working on this issue and will notify you once the issue got resolved.


Thanks & Regards,
Bharath Y M,
Software Engineer
Canarys Automations Private Limited
Mob: +91-8762575287
www.ecanarys.com